# How to get a block of data from an IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I need to get a block of data from an IEnumerable. I found a solution but I want to now if there is a more efficient solution. This is my code:
...

```
foreach (var item in pocoListToInsert)
{
   var pd = PetaPoco.Database.PocoData.ForType(pocoListToInsert.First().GetType());
   maxRecords = maxParam / pd.Columns.Count;
   if (list.Count < maxRecords)
      list.Add(item);
   else if (list.Count == maxRecords || item == lastRecord)
   {
      Insert(pd.TableInfo.TableName, pd.TableInfo.PrimaryKey, true, pocoListToInsert);
      list.Clear();
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "block of data"?

Comment: @silba: Very close to flagging this as "not a real question"; you should elaborate on *exactly* what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely don't understand you, but maybe LINQ method `Skip` and `Take` will be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Write a linq query that produces the data you want, and end it with **[`.ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)**